# Different padding in IE and chrome

Tags: css, internet-explorer

What is the possible reason for differences in padding between ie10 and chrome with `reset` applied?

[image]

http://jsbin.com/jecovuni/6/edit

Comment: Could it be the automatic inline padding on the text?

Comment: float the two inner spans left. Also set the height of the container element to 26px to match your grey box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was a problem with the `position: relative;` on the `.checkbox-icon`. If you remove the position and top and replace it with a `margin-top: -2px;` and a `vertical-align: middle;` it looks the same in Chrome and IE.

I've updated your [JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/jecovuni/15/edit). Hope this works for you!

Comment: This is an odd set of CSS. Even your updated one is slightly different in FF than Chrome and IE.